# PHP - wysiwyg style image upload?

Tags: php, image, file-upload, wysiwyg

I am rolling my own blog framework, mainly to learn how everything works.

I would like to be able to upload an image while typing my post (and be able to insert the image's  tag without refreshing the page).

Basically, the goal is to be able to embed an image with ease similar to that of a wysiwyg editor.

What is a step in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youll need to look at "ajax upload" techniques. If you google that term you should find various examples. The most common way is to use a hidden iframe to send the data.